# How can I only require authentication once with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, authentication, alamofire

I would like users of my app to be able to  log in once, establish some kind of session, then be able to make requests to the backend without further authentication.

Right now I'm having the user "login" on the frontend by entering their username and password into a UI which stores them in global variables and sends them with each request to authenticate individually. I have two problems with this:

1. This feels like a hack, it doesn't seem clean.
2. I'm not sure how
   secure this is.

I've searched through tutorials, articles, and the Alamofire README, but can't seem to find anything on this. How can I only require authentication once with Alamofire on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Alamofire and everything to do with how your backend works. It seems like you wrote it yourself, as no real backend would require you to send the username and password with every request. If you really need to do that you should store them in the keychain. But really you need to fix your backend to handle proper authenticated sessions.